# app that connects to server and uses Web API (client side)

Tags: android, iphone, webclient, client-side, asp.net-web-api

I need to create application (iPhone/android) that:

- shows login screen with username/password fields
- could create account with info provided by user (email confirmation)
- connects to server with provided credentials to retrieve token
- uses web api with provided token to store/retrieve data (but only his data, not other users data)

I am familiarized with client side programming. But I need a server that allows creation of account, login using https+basic auth (or some other mechanism), store client data and allow access to his data via web api (GET/POST/PUSH + token).

I could use FireBase but looks like it can't login user to obtain token, it needs another server to do so.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that Parse allows to create API that could have:

- users
- data
- security rules (data can be read/write only by it's user)
- user login via WEB API + token

Hope it is usefull for someone.